# No output on capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I configure my rails app to deploy with capistrano i think all config ok 
but when i do :

```
$ cap production deploy
```

I get nothing !

I do :

```
cap production deploy --trace
```

and this is the output :

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:bundler:hook (first_time)
** Execute passenger:bundler:hook
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:rvm:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:test_which_passenger (first_time)
** Execute passenger:test_which_passenger
** Execute passenger:rvm:hook
** Execute rvm:hook
** Invoke rvm:check (first_time)
** Execute rvm:check
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
.
.
.
```

this is the trace

what is the problem ?

i use passenger and nginx

Comment: That is not really enough to go on since e have no idea what your configuration looks like

Comment: lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "my_app"
set :repo_url, "repo"
set :user, 'user'

set :rvm_type, :system                     # Defaults to: :auto
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.4.0'

set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that i didn't put the server like this:

```
server "foo.com", user: "user", roles: %w{app db web}
```